# Shrink content to minSize before showing scrollbars

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

What i'm trying to achieve is that JScrollPane would show scrollbars after the content has been shrank to its minimum size. After the scrollbars show up, the panel should have its minimum size.
The closest thing i could achieve was implementing Scrollable on the jpanel and overriding getScrollableTracksViewportHeight and getScrollableTracksViewportWidth methods.

```
public class EditPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return super.getPreferredSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return 16;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return 16;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return this.getMinimumSize().width < this.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return this.getMinimumSize().height < this.getHeight();
    }
}
```

However this causes scrollbars to flicker when the content is shrank below its minimum size.

How could I achieve that without the scrollbars flickering?
Here is the code i used to test this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
        EditPanel p = new EditPanel();
        p.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        p.setBackground(Color.white);

        sp.setViewportView(p);
        f.setContentPane(sp);

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do your comparison based on the size of the viewport, not the panel:

```
@Override
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
    //return this.getMinimumSize().width < this.getWidth();
    return this.getMinimumSize().width < getParent().getWidth();
}

@Override
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
    //return this.getMinimumSize().height < this.getHeight();
    return this.getMinimumSize().height < getParent().getHeight();
}
```

Edit:

> when the scrollbars show up, EditPanels size will be preferred size instead of minimum size.

The scrollbars are based on the preferred size of the component in the viewport. So you would also need to dynamicallyl manage the preferred size. Maybe something like:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    Dimension preferredSize = super.getPreferredSize();
    Component parent = getParent();

    if (parent == null)
        return preferredSize;

    Dimension parentSize = parent.getSize();
    Dimension minimumSize = getMinimumSize();

    int width = Math.min(preferredSize.width, parentSize.width);
    width = Math.max(width, minimumSize.width);

    int height = Math.min(preferredSize.height, parentSize.height);
    height = Math.max(height, minimumSize.height);

    return new Dimension(width, height);
}
```

Comment: This kinda works, but when the scrollbars show up, EditPanels size will be preferred size instead of minimum size.